# Exclude fields from output whose attribute value matches to the condition

Tags: dataweave, mule4

With the help of mule documentation [Dataweave Reference Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-cookbook-exclude-field), i was able to remove a filed with its name but here i want to remove a field whose attribute value match to my condition.
Below is my input `XML`.

**Input XML:**

```
<users>
  <user>
    <personal_information>
        <first_name>Emiliano</first_name>
        <middle_name>Romoaldo</middle_name>
        <last_name>Lesende</last_name>
        <ssn>001-08-84382</ssn>
    </personal_information>
    <login_information>
        <info key="username">user1</info>
        <info key="password">mypassword4321</info>
    </login_information>
  </user>
</users>
```

Here, i want to remove `info` element whose `key` attribute value is **password**

Expected output should be

```
<users>
  <user>
    <personal_information>
      <first_name>Emiliano</first_name>
      <middle_name>Romoaldo</middle_name>
      <last_name>Lesende</last_name>
      <ssn>001-08-84382</ssn>
    </personal_information>
    <login_information>
      <info key="username">user1</info>
    </login_information>
  </user>
</users>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this..

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml inlineCloseOn="empty"
---
users: {
      (payload.users mapObject {
        user: {
        personal_information: $.personal_information,
        login_information: $.login_information mapObject {
            (($$) : $) if($$.@key != "password")
        }
        }
      })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked like charm. Can i have description of this solution please ?

Comment: Added another answer below. All i did in the answer posted above was make use of $$ and $ (inherent  representation for key and value in a mapObject). All i am doing is picking up key,value pairs from login_information mapObject where the attribute on key (key.@<<attributeName>>) is not equal to the string "password"

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this makes it clear..

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml inlineCloseOn="empty"
---
users: {
      (payload.users mapObject {
        user: {
        personal_information: $.personal_information,
        login_information: $.login_information mapObject(value,key,index) -> {
            ((key) : value) if(key.@key != "password")
        }
        }
      })
}
```

Comment: It is clear. So basically we are filtering output based upon condition.
Thanks for your help.